# Printing variables as many times as defined in a file (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, loops, awk

I have
`scaffold_$i` where `i in {1..3015}`
and a tab delimited file (`temp`) with 3015 values (one per line):

```
2
3
1
5
```

...

I have to print the first item scaffold_1 as many times as shown in the first line of the file, here 2, print the second item scaffold_2 3 times, the third 6 times and so on. So, that I have:

```
scaffold_1
scaffold_1
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_3
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
```

...

I have gotten to:

```
for i in {1..3};do for j in 'cat temp'; do printf 'scaffold_'$i'\n'%.0s {1..$j}; done; done
```

but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{a[NR] = $1} END {
   for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++)
      for (j=1; j <= a[i]; j++)
         print "scaffold_" i
}' file
```

```
scaffold_1
scaffold_1
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_3
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining when you get some time? I'm really into awk, but don't know that much yet. thanks!

Comment: btw how do I define so that I can print starting from 0? As in scaffold_0. thanks!

Comment: Just use `print "scaffold_" i-1` to start with `0`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you actually want to print the *value* of $scaffold_1, etc

With bash you would do

```
scaffold_1=foo 
scaffold_2=bar 
scaffold_3=foobar 
scaffold_4=qux

n=0
while read count; do 
    ((n++))
    var="scaffold_$n"
    for i in $(seq "$count"); do echo "${!var}"; done
done < temp
```

Or, with a recent bash version, use a "nameref"

```
n=0
while read count; do 
    ((n++))
    declare -n ref="scaffold_$n"
    for i in $(seq "$count"); do echo "$ref"; done
done < temp
```

```
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
foobar
qux
qux
qux
qux
qux
```

However, it's painful to see 3000 numbered variable names. Use an array

```
scaffold=(
    foo 
    bar 
    foobar 
    qux
)
n=0
while read count; do 
    for i in $(seq "$count"); do echo "${scaffold[n]}"; done
    ((n++))
done < temp
```

Comment: :) That is the other task I have to do. Thanks for anticipating!

Answer (score 1):

another minimalist `awk`

```
$ awk '{while($1--) print "scaffold_"NR}' file

scaffold_1
scaffold_1
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_2
scaffold_3
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
scaffold_4
```